# What's the new location of credentials.json for dart/flutter pub

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I noticed that after switching to the beta channel (Flutter 2.9.0-0.1.pre), `~/.pub-cache/credentials.json` no longer exists. I was using this file to set up CI jobs to deploy my Flutter packages. Where did it go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it was moved to the following locations:

> On Linux:
>
> - If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is defined:
>
>   - $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dart/pub-credentials.json
> - else
>
>   - $HOME/.config/dart/pub-credentials.json
>
> On Mac OS:
>
> - ~/Library/Application Support/dart/pub-credentials.json
>
> On Windows:
>
> - %APPDATA%/dart/pub-credentials.json

(Source: [dart-lang/pub#2999 - Do not store credentials in PUB_CACHE](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2999#issuecomment-908350917))

(Relevant code: https://github.com/dart-lang/cli_util/blob/master/lib/cli_util.dart#L88)

---

On GitHub Actions, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` was defined, so I do the following:

```yaml
- name: Prepare pub credentials
  run: echo '${{ secrets.PUB_CREDENTIALS }}' > "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dart/pub-credentials.json"
```

Comment: /home/runner/.config/dart/pub-credentials.json: No such file or directory
issue can be fixed with `run: mkdir -p $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dart && echo '${{ secrets.PUB_CREDENTIALS }}' > "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dart/pub-credentials.json"`

Comment: seems confusing, if you want to view the json file in window, goto "C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\dart\pub-credentials.json". 
Note: make sure you login with "dart pub publish" first